# React native cloudscraper to catch page code

Tags: javascript, http, react-native, web-scraping, get

I'm trying to make an http request to get the html code of the page but the page uses cloudscraper, so I'm using a module to do this.

But the module is not working, it does not seem to be making the call, or it does not print anything to a problem.

Link: [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/Bys6_SWF4)

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import * as cloudscraper from 'react-native-cloudscraper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('1');
    cloudscraper
      .get('https://ilgeniodellostreaming.pw/?s=avenger')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(responseHtml => {
        console.log('r: ', responseHtml.substring(0, 5000));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    console.log('2');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to
          get a shareable url.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I was curious about react-native-cloudscraper but their github page is 404'd

Comment: I know, that's why I asked here, it is based on what I know about the following library: https://github.com/codemanki/cloudscraper